# How to use a dynamic number of yield statements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, yield

```
  def within_page_frame
    application_tab = window_opened_by { click_link('Application Info') }
    within_window application_tab do
    within_frame find_by_id('ApplicationInfo') do
      yield
      end
    end
 end

 it 'should view the web page', :smoke do
   visit_home_page p
   application_tab = window_opened_by { click_link('Application Info') }
   within_page_frame {expect(find_by_id('home page').to be}
 end
```

Here is code that is currently working. I am using the method "within_page_frame" to avoid repeating code in other specs in my test suite.

What I would like to do is be able to pass in **multiple expect statements** without having to specify the exact number of yield statements in the within_page_frame method. Is there a way to have a **dynamic number of yield statements** in my method so that I can pass in any number of expect statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
within_page_frame do 
  expect(find_by_id('home page')).to be
  expect(find_by_id('something else')).to be
end
```